# Stopping background javascript activity on location-triggered bluetooth-central iOS wakes

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

I'm using the [Cordova Gimbal plugin](https://github.com/happydenn/cordova-plugin-gimbal2) to monitor bluetooth beacons in the background. iOS wakes up the app while in the background to send it bluetooth beacon sighting events; the [Gimbal SDK](https://docs.gimbal.com/iosdocs/v2/devguide.html) processes these and calls a objc handler function in the plugin. I've removed any code that fires events on the window object in an attempt to prevent any javascript from running while in the 10-second execution window.

However, javascript executes anyway on these background events: my app uses Angular, and expensive `$digest` cycles continue in the background. `$interval` (wrapper for `setInterval()`) works too. It seems that while the app is running in the 10-second window, it just keeps on running the javascript engine as if it were in the foreground. This is significantly affecting battery usage for the app. How can I get the cordova event loop to just stop executing when it's done handling the beacon sighting?

versions: cordova 6.5.0 cordova-ios 4.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the javascript engine doesn't run opportunistically like this if we switch to using WKWebView. So, adding [this plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) (and fixing the fallout from the switch) fixed the issue.